# Why are chrome textareas sizing themselves two columns more to fit a possible scrollbar when overflow:hidden and resize:none?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I want chrome to size my textarea exactly as many columns as I specify. Not an extra two.

Firefox and IE are kind enough to make my textarea as many 'cols' as I specify when the scrollbars are turned off with styles "overflow:hidden" and "resize:none". Why can't chrome do the same? Is there a css styling that chrome obeys to fix this?

If it can't be fixed, how can I test in javascript whether textareas are rendering N + 2 columns wide when its 'cols' attribute is set to 'N' in the markup?

try this:

```
<textarea style="overflow:hidden; resize:none;" cols=10 rows=1>1234567890</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o7p31sob/

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to share your CSS and HTML, and possibly a jsFiddle.

Comment: good plan, i'll get back shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by using `width:10ch;` explicitly. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftd1Lrdg/2/).

The full CSS I came up with is:

```
textarea{
    width:auto; /* Default */
    width:10ch; /* 10 characters for webkit */
    width:auto\9; /* Fix for IE */
}
```

Comment: Helpful, but I can't use it. I'm just trying to make a textarea that's only as big as it needs to be. Not an easy feat! So I'm resizing it at runtime. I could just size two less columns, but I was hoping for a css solution that would fix chrome but not break any other browser. In this situation IE breaks if I fix chrome. So now I have to detect chrome in JS and subtract two I guess.

Comment: It's working for me on IE 10. On which version does it break?

Comment: breaks on 11. I opened your fiddle in it and its not showing all the characters. It actually obeys the width:Nch but different numbers yield different results between chrome and ie 11. Firefox is peachy.

Comment: On Chrome, Set the rows to 2 in the fiddle and watch what happens when you put the cursor before the 9 and spacebar the 9 and 0 to the next line. Keep pressing space.. The 9 and the 0 lock in position. I hate that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm setting the column size in javascript anyway, I fixed it for now doing this:

```
var textareanode = getTextAreaNode();
var cols = calculateCols();
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if (is_chrome)
   cols = cols - 2;
setCols(cols, textareanode);
```